Java SpringBoot JPA calling deleteById() on an entity with oneToMany() childs and oneToone() parent does not delete the child
I setup a simple hierarchy: Parent, Child, Subchild. a parent has one child, a child has oneToMany subchildren. I call childRepository.deleteById(), it does not delete neither the child nor the subchildren and it does not throw an error.  Minimal setup to reproduce the issue:
Parent.Java:
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Child oneChild;
}

Child.Java:
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Child {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "child", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<SubChild> subChilds = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Parent parent;
}

SubChild.Java:
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBCHILD")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SubChild {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Child child;
}

controller.Java:
private final ChildRepository childRepository;

public void deleteChild(Long id) {
        childRepository.deleteById(id);
    }


What do you expect to happen to your Parent instances that still reference that child, and what do you think the 'cascade' option on the Parent.oneChild should do to the child instance it still references that you are deleting? Putting it another way: you cannot delete the child until you convince the parent to let go first.
